# Run SQL through JDBC, how to parameterize Table Names

Tags: oracle, postgresql, jdbc

If I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Test_Persons_A 
(
    PersonID int,
    LastName varchar(255),
    FirstName varchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO Test_Persons_A (PersonID, LastName, FirstName)
VALUES (11, 'LN_A1', 'FN_A1');

INSERT INTO Test_Persons_A (PersonID, LastName, FirstName)
VALUES (12, 'LN_A2', 'FN_A2');

CREATE TABLE Test_Persons_B 
(
    PersonID int,
    LastName varchar(255),
    FirstName varchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO Test_Persons_B (PersonID, LastName, FirstName)
VALUES (21, 'LN_B1', 'FN_B1');

INSERT INTO Test_Persons_B (PersonID, LastName, FirstName)
VALUES (22, 'LN_B2', 'FN_B2');

commit;
```

The effect I want to achieve is equivalent to executing each the following two queries from java code through JDBC (oracle)

Block A:

```
select PersonID as PID, LastName as LN, FirstName as FN
    from Test_Persons_A tp
    where tp.LASTNAME like '%1%'
```

Block B:

```
select PersonID as PID, LastName as LN, FirstName as FN
    from Test_Persons_B tp
    where tp.LASTNAME like '%2%'
```

You can see that the only difference are:

- Table Name
- LASTNAME cretiria

But in my case, each of the the blocks are in fact a huge 'With...Select...' clause, and the java code (legacy, I can't change an iota) in fact reads each sql block from a .sql file as below before executing it through JDBC.

- hugeQueryA.sql
- hugeQueryB.sql

My question is: to avoid duplicating this huge block of code, instead, is it the best to construct a single large stored procedure (or functions)?

- hugeStoredProc

put it in my DB, then construct two simple sql

- simpleQueryA.sql
- simpleQueryB.sql

to call the stored procedure with parameters (specified in each of the sql)?

- Can I do this without having to use Dynamic SQL (since to do that I assume I will need change the content of the original huge sql files into strings and handle all the special chars - plus, would that also going to look awful?)?
- More generally, when I need to 'parameterize' the table name, and can't use 'substitution variables', is dynamic SQL the only way to go?

Answer (score 2):

Table names can't be parameterized, but you can use string substitution to generate the desired SQL after loading in your .sql file(s), provided the table names you're substituting in aren't based on user input.

For example, you could change:

```
from Test_Persons_A tp
```

to:

```
from {TableName} tp
```

After you load the file, use string substitution to replace "{TableName}" with the actual table name, then execute.

Comment: thanks pancake but i cannot change any of the java code in this case